# System.InvalidOperationException when using GetAwaiter().GetResult() with ServiceBusReceiver.PeekMessagesAsync

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, iasyncenumerable

#### Context

We are using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` because PowerShell's `Cmdlet.ProcessRecord()` does not support async/await.

#### Code Sample

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var topicPath = "some-topic";
        var subscriptionName = "some-subscription";
        var connectionString = "some-connection-string";

        var subscriptionPath = EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(
            topicPath,
            subscriptionName
        );

        var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
        var receiver = serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(queueName: subscriptionPath);

        // This one works. :-) 
        await foreach (var item in GetMessages(receiver, maxMessagesPerFetch: 5))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("async/await: " + item);
        }

        // This one explodes.
        var enumerator = GetMessages(receiver, maxMessagesPerFetch: 5).GetAsyncEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNextAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
            // Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
            //    at NonSync.IAsyncEnumerable.Program.GetMessages(ServiceBusReceiver receiver, Int32 maxMessagesPerFetch)+System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Boolean>.GetResult()
            //    at NonSync.IAsyncEnumerable.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dev\mediavalet\MediaValet.Learning\entropy\NonSynchronousDotNet\NonSync.IAsyncEnumerable\Program.cs:line 42
            //    at NonSync.IAsyncEnumerable.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
            Console.WriteLine("GetAwaiter().GetResult(): " + enumerator.Current);
        }
    }

    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetMessages(
        ServiceBusReceiver receiver,
        int maxMessagesPerFetch
    )
    {
        yield return "Foo";
        var messages = await receiver.PeekMessagesAsync(maxMessagesPerFetch);
        yield return "Bar";
    }
}
```

## Question

What's going on here? How can we fix it without changing `GetMessages`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [`ValueTask<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1) struct:

> The following operations should never be performed on a `ValueTask<TResult>` instance:
>
> • Awaiting the instance multiple times.
> • Calling `AsTask` multiple times.
> • Using `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` when the operation hasn't yet completed, or using them multiple times.
> • Using more than one of these techniques to consume the instance.
>
> If you do any of the above, the results are undefined.

What you can do is to convert the `ValueTask<bool>` to a `Task<bool>`, by using the [`AsTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.astask) method:

```
while (enumerator.MoveNextAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult())
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer complements Theodor's answer with a code sample. Our specific problem was that we were calling `GetResult()` before the `ValueTask` had completed. The docs specify that that is not allowed:

> A ValueTask instance may only be awaited once, and **consumers may not read Result until the instance has completed.** If these limitations are unacceptable, convert the ValueTask to a Task by calling AsTask. (Emphasis added).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var enumerator = GetAsyncEnumerable().GetAsyncEnumerator();

while (true)
{
    var moveNext = enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
    var moveNextAwaiter = moveNext.GetAwaiter();

    Console.WriteLine("ValueTask.IsCompleted: {0}", moveNext.IsCompleted);

    try
    {
        if (moveNextAwaiter.GetResult())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IAsyncEnumerator.Current: {0}", enumerator.Current);
            continue;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done! We passed the end of the collection.");
        break;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Boom! GetResult() before the ValueTask completed.");
        continue;
    }
}

async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetAsyncEnumerable()
{
    yield return 1;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    yield return 2; // <---- We never access this, because GetResult() explodes.
    yield return 3;
}
```

Output:

```
ValueTask.IsCompleted: True
IAsyncEnumerator.Current: 1

ValueTask.IsCompleted: False
Boom! GetResult() before the ValueTask completed.

ValueTask.IsCompleted: True
IAsyncEnumerator.Current: 3

ValueTask.IsCompleted: True
Done! We passed the end of the collection.
```